# Angular Material Datepicker acting weirdly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material2

[Click here to see the appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY1PR.png)
Angular Material date picker is acting weirdly, when selected on the icon the calendar appears to be very big. Is any else facing this issue.

app.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatePicker">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #myDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

app.model.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule}    from '@angular/forms';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'

// import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material/moment-adapter";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
MatInputModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[The screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNEB9.png)

Comment: It looks like your CSS news some work

Comment: it seems there was CSS load issue, check for console error and if there is error send here to get better help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good to have you. Could you add a screeshot to make "acting weirdly" visible? While you are on it, check the browser console for messages and, if you find some, add them to the question

Comment: @mpora I have added the image of the console message

Comment: As mentioned in the console you are missing Angular Material core theme, click on the link provided in the console to find out how to set up the default Angular Material theme and you should be ok.